# Trouble with grub

Tags: grub2, 18.04

Sorry for my Bad English. So, I have a trouble with grub. I have Windows 10 and I would install Ubuntu 18.04. After I installed Ubuntu my Windows OS disappeared. `os-prober` Don't help me, because writes nothing to the console. I Have configuration of Windows in Grub Customize.

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,2)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 4CE2F22DE2F21AC2
chainloader +1
}
```

And I have next errors:

```
Error: File "/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod" is not found.
Error: no such device: 4CE2F22DE2F21AC2.
Error: invalid EFI file path.
```

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Most common issues are Windows 10 fast start up is still on, or you installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode with Windows in UEFI mode. Report will show details we need to suggest fix.

Comment: @oldfred I use Boot-Repair. I delete grub from /dev/sda10 and installed it in /dev/sda. And with Grub Customize i make windows settings with configuration which i showed upper.